# How to reject an array block with particular condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, wsdl

Here is the array. I need to reject the array block who has item_id == 200.

```
:invoice_lines=>[{:amount=>"60.00", :description=>"repair   call",:id=>"10138500", :item_id=>"80062",  :price=>"60.0000000000"}, 
{:amount=>"9.83", :description=>"Tax", :id=>"10138501", :item_id=>"200", :price=>"8.1875000000"}, 
{:amount=>"60.00",  :description=>"Wireless Router", :id=>"10138502", :item_id=>"80060", :price=>"60.0000000000"}]
```

I am trying this way but can't get the result.

```
  i = 0
  num = invoice[:invoice_lines].length
  items = []
  while i < num
    if invoice[:invoice_lines][i][item_id] == 200
       invoice[:invoice_lines].delate_at(i)
    end
    i += 1
  end
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I wonder... could there be [a method that does just that](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reject-21)?

Comment: Try `num.reject { |n| n[:item_id] == "200" }` and change `num = invoice[:invoice_lines].length` to `num = invoice[:invoice_lines]`

Comment: `ruby-on-rails` tag was removed?

Comment: @Pavan was the culprit, but it seems justified.

Comment: @CarySwoveland  Sorry! I might be misjudged the question, but its complete ***Ruby***

Comment: @Pavan Its all right man! :)

Comment: @Pavan, shouldn't that be `reject!`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Aah! yes :)

Comment: @Pavan, or `num.each { |n| n[:item_id]=="200 || n.delete(:item_id) }; num`. `reject!` also needs `; num` at the end in case no elements are deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
array = []

invoice[:invoice_lines].each do |line|
  array << line unless line[:item_id] == "200"
end unless invoice[:invoice_lines].blank?

array
```

`array` will return all the invoice lines with `item_id` not equal to `200`

**or**

As mentioned in the comments by **ndn**, you can use `reject` if you want to remove the hashes from `invoice[:invoice_lines]`, http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reject-21

Hope that helps!